# jQuery step by step form variables

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering how to collect data variables in the step by step form that I've been working on at the moment.

It can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/xSkgH/22/

There are a variety of input methods and I am trying to collate all the information collected by the user dynamically (i.e. if the user goes back to change something it will update automatically) on the "final stage".

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. It seems simple. I think I got your question correctly. See if this is what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/xSkgH/30/

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you so much! So will I be able to store these values as variables ready for AJAX submission?

Comment: @CJS yes , like this.. `var paraData="capacity="+FormData[0]+"&date="+ FormData[1]+"&grade="+FormData[2]; ` and use  paraData as AJAX data. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/xSkgH/31/

Comment: I've tested the code and there seems to be one problem. Each time you go back then forward there is a bug that seems to add more and more values on. How can I fix this?

Comment: Because we are using '.append()' method , use '.html()'. Check if this is what you want? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/xSkgH/38/

Answer (score 1):

Possible thinks that i know are:

- saving all in parameters
- saving it to js variables
- saving it to hidden fields
- use the session object
- saving into a cookie